# Webmin on Debian 7 Lamp

Tags: linux, debian, webmin

I accidentally renamed the etc folder, webmin and all services stopped. How I can to rename it back ? Rescue system works but I don't know what commands need to use in terminal..

Comment: It might sound stupid, but can't you rename it back?  If you don't know how to do this, how did you do it the first time?  Regardless of the above, you can rename a directory using the `mv` command, like `mv /etc_bad/ /etc/`.  I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Renaming (and moving) of files and directories is done via `mv`. Just pass the old name and the new name as parameters. Example:

> mv /foo /etc

Note: If the destination (in this case `/etc`) already *exists*, `mv` will *move* `/foo` inside `/etc` so that it becomes `/etc/foo`.

In order to see what `mv` actually does, you can add the `-v` parameter. Example:

> mv -v /foo /etc

This will show you exactly if it *renamed* and/or *moved* the given file or directory. In the case of *renaming*, it will show you something like:

> ‘/foo’ -> ‘/etc’

and if it *moved* the directory it will show instead:

> ‘/foo’ -> ‘/etc/foo’

Comment: I mean that rescue system runs completely in memory without using the local disk. I can't see my etc folder there... pls help

Comment: Then you have to `mount` it first.

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball broke last week :/ What's the error message?